# How to check if a file is already marked for add?

Tags: version-control, perforce

I'd like to check if a file is already locally marked for add, without adding the said file. Is this check possible with a Perforce command?

Comment: In addition to the answers you've already received, there is also `p4 opened //path/to/file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if a file is marked for add by running the [fstat command](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r14.2/manuals/cmdref/p4_fstat.html). If the command output contains the string `"action add"`, that means the file is already marked for add.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `-n` option it will preview the add operation telling you which files would be added but not actually adding the file.

[Source](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.2/manuals/cmdref/add.html)

```
p4 add -n testfile
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally use below two commands:

```
p4 diff -sa  // to show list of all opened files

p4 diff -se  // to show list of all files that are with changes but not opened
```